# Efficient copy method between two C++/CX Platform::Array:s?

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, copy, c++-cx

I want to copy a sequence of items in a `Platform::Array` object to another `Platform::Array`. I can of course solve this for example with a `for` loop:

```
int srcIdx = srcIdx0;
int destIdx = destIdx0;
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i, ++srcIdx, ++destIdx)
    dest[destIdx] = src[srcIdx];
```

What I am wondering is, is there some built-in functionality in C++/CX (Component Extensions) for performing this operation more efficiently and less verbose?

In C#, there is the [Array.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft.aspx) method, and with C++/CLI [Marshal.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4cew0s1h.aspx) would be an option at least for copying "primitive" types.

In C++ STL, there is `std::copy` and `std::copy_n`, but from what I can tell these algorithms do not work with `Platform::Array` "iterators" `begin()` and `end()`.

Is there a C++/CX convenience copy method "hidden" somewhere, or do I have to fallback on explicit `for` loops for this operation?

Comment: Did you try with `Platform::Array`'s `begin()` and `end()`? I can be wrong, but I thought they were designed for STL compatibility...

Comment: Thanks, Mr.C64. I get compilation error when I try to use these with `std::copy_n`. According to the error message I can overrule the error by compiling with the preprocessor directive _DRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS (or something similar). I am not comfortable with such an approach, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point in time there seem to be no built-in `Platform::Array` copy methods, so I have implemented my own template function for the purpose:

```
template<typename T> void Copy(
    const Platform::Array<T>^ sourceArray, 
    int sourceIndex, 
    Platform::Array<T>^ destinationArray, 
    int destinationIndex, 
    int length)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i, ++sourceIndex, ++destinationIndex)
        destinationArray[destinationIndex] = sourceArray[sourceIndex];
};
```

Suggestions on how to improve the copying part are more than welcome :-)

Comment: Suggestion - use the ->Length property of each array so you don't overwrite the source.